# How to read an Open Office spreadsheet?

Tags: groovy, openoffice.org

How can I read an Open Office 3.0 spreadsheet (.ods) from Groovy?  I'd like to select specific columns from a named worksheet.  Ideally, it would be useful to add a 'where' clause, or other criteria clause.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used it, but [Open Office has a Java API](http://api.openoffice.org/), which of course you could use from Groovy as well.  It looks like the best places to start reading are the [Developer's Guide](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/OpenOffice.org_Developers_Guide), the [Java UNO Reference](http://api.openoffice.org/docs/java/ref/overview-summary.html), and the samples in [Java](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/API/Samples/Java) and (hey!) [Groovy](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/API/Samples/Groovy).  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Might be something here at [Spring Factories](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Using+Spring+Factories+with+Groovy) or here at [Groovy and JMX](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Groovy+and+JMX). There is a forum for [Groovy and Open Office](https://sourceforge.net/forum/forum.php?forum_id=708126).

Answer (score 0):

Could you export the table / spreadsheet as SQL entries then use that. You could also look at this plugin for goovy -- [http://www.ifcx.org/](http://www.ifcx.org/wiki/GroovyForOpenOffice.html)

Answer (score 0):

OpenOffice documents are ZIP files which contains the document data as XML plus some other files (style sheets for word documents). [Details can be found here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument_technical_specification).

The main problem with calc is formulas. If you just have tabular data, then you can simply read the cell values and use that. So you can open the ZIP archive, read the `content.xml` in it and parse that with any XML parser.

But when a cell contains a formula, then you need to execute it. In this case, you will have to open the document via the UNO API. [Here is the Java version](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/java/ref/overview-summary.html). There is a link where you can download example code that explains how to open ODF documents and how to examine their content. [There are also snippets](http://codesnippets.services.openoffice.org/Calc/java.xml) but none of them show how to examine a sheet.

The main disadvantage of UNO is the documentation. Each method is explained somewhere but you have to find the method which solves your problem, first.

Answer (score -1):

*Since the title does not mention Groovy (only question specifics does), I didn't want to make this a new question.*

How to generally read an Open Office spreadsheet document?  There are tools for creating one (ooo-python) but not for reading one. They are XML but just bluntly diving into that and trying to get the right logic of extracting the data I want seems so sub-optimal.

What I'd like is features similar to Excel COM support, but from a command line tool (or scripting language).

Comment: -1 Don't post more questions in the answers section. Open a new question if your specific details aren't answered and possibly link to this question ("Like this question but I need to know...")